# How can I ensure that my PDF reading code does not return a NaN row and a duplicate row?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp

I am working on reading PDF files that are CVs into a DataFrame (pandas). However, after reading the files I find a NaN row and a duplicate row of the last CV (alphabetically). Is there something in the code that does this? I can't seem to figure out why. I have tried changing around the iloc index[0] parts and the fileIndex value, but have found no solution. All help is appreciated.

```
dataset = []

pdf_dir = "C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs/"
pdf_files = glob.glob("%s/*.pdf" % pdf_dir)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['FileName','Text'])
fileIndex = 0

for file in pdf_files:

  pdfFileObj = open(file,'rb')     #'rb' for read binary mode
  pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

  startPage = 0
  text = ''
  cleanText = ''
  while startPage <= pdfReader.numPages-1:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(startPage)
    text += pageObj.extractText()
    startPage += 1
  pdfFileObj.close()
  for myWord in text:
    if myWord != '\n':
      cleanText += myWord
  text = cleanText.split()
  newRow = pd.DataFrame(index = [0], columns = ['FileName', 'Text'])
  newRow.iloc[0]['FileName'] = file
  newRow.iloc[0]['Text'] = text
  dataset = pd.concat([output_data, newRow], ignore_index=True)
```

Here is a list of the PDF files currently in the directory:
[PDF files in directory][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UJZQ.png

This is the result:

```
    FileName    Text
0   NaN NaN
1   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\1... [Copyright, ©, 1996-2018,, JobStreet.com., All...
2   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\1... [AMY, PROFILE, Fund, accountant, with, nearly,...
3   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\2... [BEN, Fund, Accoutant, Sep, 2016, -, Present, ...
4   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\3... [CARRIE, Professional, Experience, Citco, Fund...
5   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\4... [DICKSON, PROFESSIONAL, EXPERIENCE, Conifer, F...
6   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\5... [EDWARDO, QUALIFICATION, SUMMARY, Results-driv...
7   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\6... [FAYE, Citco, Fund, Services, (Singapore), Pte...
8   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\7... [GIRAFFE, Work, Experience:, CITCO, Fund, Serv...
9   C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\8... [Career, Objectives, Have, strong, interest, i...
10  C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\9... [IGNATIUS, Work, Experience, Watiga, &, Co., (...
11  C:/Users/user/Documents/CV ML Test/CVs\9... [IGNATIUS, Work, Experience, Watiga, &, Co., (...
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the following part of the code:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['FileName','Text'])
for file in pdf_files:

  pdfFileObj = open(file,'rb')     #'rb' for read binary mode
  pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

  startPage = 0
  text = ''
  cleanText = ''
  while startPage <= pdfReader.numPages-1:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(startPage)
    text += pageObj.extractText()
    startPage += 1
  pdfFileObj.close()
  for myWord in text:
    if myWord != '\n':
      cleanText += myWord
  text = cleanText.split()
  newRow = pd.DataFrame(index = [0], columns = ['FileName', 'Text'])
  newRow.iloc[0]['FileName'] = file
  newRow.iloc[0]['Text'] = text
  dataset = pd.concat([dataset, newRow], ignore_index= True )
```

Notice last line has changed list parameter to match first part. "dataset" instead of output_data.